# Django project: ImportError: No module named elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

pip install elasticsearch

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): elasticsearch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3<2.0,>=1.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from elasticsearch)

But when I run the python,

python es.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "es.py", line 1, in 
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
ImportError: No module named elasticsearch

Comment: `which python` ? that will tell you if you are using the correct virtualenv

Comment: python 2.7.. Django framework!

Comment: no when you type which python it will tel you the path to the python executable. That's what we need to know